# virtual ip address-how it works and uses of it

Tags: networking, network-adapter, ip-address

My questions are:

How having an ip address for an application is useful?

Does packets coming to application have virtual ip address as destination ip address or physical ip address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you might be confused between what is an [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and a [socket address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).

Comment: as far as i know virtual ip address can be assigned to an application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How having an ip address for an application is useful?

You cannot have two programs listening on the same TCP/IP port on a single system.

You can have a "proxy" or "filter" program listening on a port, and then distributing requests to another port on the same system or the same port on a different system.

So each listening application on a system should already have a locally unique "address" (in this case, the TCP/IP port).  So it is not useful.  It would just be extra complexity for no benefit.

> Does packets coming to application have virtual ip address as destination ip address or physical ip address?

You can tell a program (such as a server) to listen on a specific IP address/specific port, several specific IP addresses/specific port, or ALL IP addresses/specific port (most TCP/IP stacks use 0.0.0.0 to mean "any IP").

So if the system this program is running on has an interface (say eth0) that has IP 254.1.2.3, and traffic comes in on that interface, incoming packets will have their source IP and 254.1.2.3 as the destination IP.

Keep in mind you can do things like create virtual interfaces.  It's helpful to always remember IP addresses are assigned to *interfaces* and not *machines*, and a machine can have more than 1 interface - most do (i.e. LAN and WLAN interfaces, etc.).